# Dynamically Splitting Column of a DataFrame and Store it as a New Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I am trying to split a column and store the part after the last "_" as a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
names= ['John', 'Jane', 'Brian','Suzan', 'John']
expertise = ['primary_chat', 'follow_email', 'repeat_chat', 'primary_video_chat', 'tech_chat']

data  = list(zip(names,expertise))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Communication'])
df
```

**Output**

```
    Name       Communication
0   John        primary_chat
1   Jane        follow_email
2  Brian         repeat_chat
3  Suzan  primary_video_chat
4   John           tech_chat
```

When I add a new column by splitting the column:

```
df['Platform'] = df['Communication'].str.split('_', expand=True)[1]
df
```

**Output**

```
    Name       Communication Platform
0   John        primary_chat     chat
1   Jane        follow_email    email
2  Brian         repeat_chat     chat
3  Suzan  primary_video_chat    video
4   John           tech_chat     chat
```

But the problem is that, [1] takes the 2nd part of the split. This is not a problem when we only have one "_", the 2nd part is what we need. But when you have 2 "_"s like the 3rd one (Suzan), the [1] gets you the phrase "video" not the "email", we should have [2] indexing there.

We can dynamically get the number of "_"s and use this value but, the below code even though it outputs correct values, when I use it in [] as an index value I get an error.

```
df['Communication'].str.count('_')
```

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    1
Name: Communication, dtype: int64
```

gives me the correct number of "_". But when I try to use it in the previous line of code where I use split() and create the new column, I get an error

```
df['Platform'] = df['Communication'].str.split('_', expand=True)[df['Agent Expertise'].str.count('_')]
```

But I am getting error..

Maybe I should try to use apply() and lambda but I wonder if there is a way to fix this one..

Comment: *the [1] gets you the phrase "video" not the "email"*: why "email" and not "chat" for Suzan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.rsplit` and limit the number of splits to 1:

```
df['Platform'] = df['Communication'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[1]
print(df)

# Output
    Name       Communication Platform
0   John        primary_chat     chat
1   Jane        follow_email    email
2  Brian         repeat_chat     chat
3  Suzan  primary_video_chat     chat
4   John           tech_chat     chat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression that looks for all characters but `_` at the end of string (represented by `$`):

```
df['Platform'] = df['Communication'].str.extract('([^_]+)$')
```